# Error in sql.. im using in phpmy admin

Tags: mysql, sql

below error is happening from the sql query mentioned below the error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[testing] GO /****** Object: Table [dbo].[AdminMaster] Script
>   Date: ' at line 1

```
USE [testing]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AdminMaster]    Script Date: 03/16/2014 23:06:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminMaster](
[AdminName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[AdminPassword] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[AdminMasterId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_voipAdminMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[AdminMasterId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]   
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Looks like it's not MySQL syntax. May be MS SQL?

Comment: ya u right it is ms sql only